# Autocomplete move from 2003 to 2010 new PC

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, autocomplete, templates

Im trying to get a users old settings from word 2003 to 2010, i've got the marcos moved but not working but will deal with them later.

The main issuse is with moving auto text when they press F3. Iv tried moving the old normal.dot to every folder within windows 7! eg C:\users\bob\appdata\roaming\microsoft(templates, startup, building blocks etc etc etc but its simply not working.

Also tried replacing the new notmal.dotm with the old one but didnt work.

I would love some help as i have 20 odd PC's to roll out. Is there a tool that can do this?

Comment: Please review the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq). This is not a forum. Do not post answers, but rather comment on answers to get more info.

Answer (score 1):

have you taken a look at this article from MS

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-autotext-HA010255209.aspx

Comment: Yes i have tried this but it didnt work, just gave me a new default font.